# Asked valid question, was having discussion in comments, question was suddenly closed with no comment to indicate why

Tags: support

[New user logs in through RDP on Windows System and Public\Desktop items don't show up on their desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1599189/new-user-logs-in-through-rdp-on-windows-system-and-public-desktop-items-dont-sh)

This is a problem that I'm encountering all the time in my environment.
Question was closed without any comments.
I even ask if theres any investigation I can do to give more information.

Comment: It would probably be better asked at [sf] in my opinion.

Comment: I guess so but wouldn't be nice if the new flock of reviewers would simply leave a comment for me ?  I mean you can suggest that I go to serverfault and somone may have had that idea but looking at the question, it is equally a user-system problem.

Comment: I asked for more information several times.  I literally only heard crickets.

Comment: This is riduclous Ramhound. Someone else closed my question... without comment... before you showed up. I got lots of good information and have yet to respond. I don't know why you've gotten this idea that this post is about you. It isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question was closed without any comments.

This is false.  I provided some feedback and it was ignored.  Even now the question is missing vital information that only appears in commentary you submitted.

However, instead of responding to our feedback, you decided to respond negatively.

> [Trying to get my original post opened because your reviewer gremlins closed it based on superficially. Please reopen my question, it was not appropriate to close it in the first place](https://superuser.com/questions/1599252/why-dont-my-public-desktop-shortcuts-show-up-in-new-users-desktop-folders)

I only decided to submit this answer after you submitted that comment.

> In my original question that started all this... the question was 1.
> Closed without comment...end of story. Ask a Stack Exchange moderator if you
> don't believe me. 2. In scope for Super User. 3. Closed at the whims of
> newbie reviewers.

1. **I actually provided feedback to your original question.**  Instead of editing that question, you submitted a new question, and improved that question. Since you submitted the same question, which had already been closed, when I flagged your second question it was closed by a moderator as a duplicate. **The only feedback to my feedback was the sound of crickets.**
2. The question was within scope but being out of scope wasn't the reason it was closed.  **Only in it's current form, does it stand a chance to be reopened, but **I won't issue a reopen vote since I am human and I don't like being called a gremlin.**
3. The question was absolutely not closed by "the whims of newbie reviewers".  I was one of those reviewers.  **I still maintain your question still does not contain enough information.**  In reality your question was original [reviewed](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1015597) by some of the most experienced users in the community.  It was [reviewed](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1016571) a second time by three additional users.  **To indicate these 6 users are new to reviewing content in the reopen queue isn't civil behavior**

I want to make one thing clear, and this is supported by the question history, I voted to keep your question closed before you made some of the improvements.  **I could vote to reopen the question, but being called a gremlin isn't fun, so I skipped the vote to reopened it last time I reviewed it.**

Comment: Ramhound, in my original question that started all this... the question was 1. Closed without comment...end of story. Ask a Stackex sysadmin if you don't believe me. 2. In scope for SuperUser. 3. Closed at the whims of newbie reviewers.  ........ I understand your position about the quality of the question but it does not make it right to have closed it and especially without comment.

Comment: I submitted feedback to your original question. That feedback was ignored.

Comment: No, I highly value your feedback.

Comment: Ramhound is not the target of the complaint. I did post another question because it was unfair to have closed the first. Ramhound did not close the first, Ramhound may have been on the receiving end for the second question yet quite indirectly as I was still trying to have my question heard... from the first question which again was not closed by Ramhound. Ramhound showed up to offer assistance, there are still comments left by him that I haven't been able to gather information for. Very confusing situation now that the user has taken something not directed at them and taken offense. RIP this

Comment: @estrando - You have to understand.  I am an active reviewer.  If you make comment like "reviewer gremlins" you have inverently include a ton of people, including myself, you shouldn't have called anyone a "reviewer gremlin".

Comment: Ok I also review, obviously not with this account and if someone complained that they'd be unfairly closed on and referred to reviewer gremlins, then I'd be like Hey that guy doesnt like being closed on. I understand you took it personally which is terrible and I don't want you to feel that way. I don't want you to take it on. I do believe strongly that the question was improperly closed and it was the last straw for me who over the years has been, as many are, improperly closed on. There are, as I hope you agree, many reviewers that really don't care about their doing and thus I can't recant.

Comment: @estrando - Apologizing is the first step.  I issued a vote to reopen the question.  Hopefully, you don’t call us gremlins, because were actually *underwear Gnomes*.